# Redirect when closing tab?

Tags: javascript

Whenever a visitor goes to close the tab, this code shows them a message:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
}
```

However, this is the code I can't get to work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Why wouldn't this code redirect the visitor to example.com when they go to close the tab?  Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You can use `location.assign('http://www.google.com');` or    `window.open("http://www.google.com","newwindow");` to redirect user,

Comment: Some browsers ignore the `unbeforeunload` since it's commonly used by pop-ups. Why do you want to redirect before closing a tab?

Comment: I think that would be a security issue - user expects something and website redirects them back in - could only be for bad purposes

Comment: @fizakhan The `location.assign` method doesn't appear to redirect or popup a new tab.  The `window.open` method is blocked by almost all browsers.

Comment: @Stacker visit this page https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-redirect-using-javascript/ here all of the methods are listed to redirect user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `location.replace()`, use the canonical `window.location` property like so:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // use jquery version older than 1.6
    var preventUnloadPrompt;
    var messageBeforeUnload = "my message here - Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
    $('a').live('click', function() { preventUnloadPrompt = true; });
    $('form').live('submit', function() { preventUnloadPrompt = true; });

      function request() {
            setTimeout(function() {
              window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank');
            });
        }

    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(e) { 
        
        var rval;
        if(preventUnloadPrompt) {
            return;

        } else {
            request();

            return messageBeforeUnload;
        }

        return rval;
    })
```